# A magic grasshopper

Tags: mathematics

A magic grasshopper sits at the origin of a number line. He can jump a distance of 1, 2, 4, 8, ... or any whole power of 2 in either direction. What is the smallest distance from the origin that requires at least 4 jumps?

Comment: 2^n * 4? Anyways I'm kinda confused as to what you mean.

Comment: I tried to reword it, so hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: I got 32+8+2+1=43

Comment: @newQOpenWid can you put that as an answer instead and explain how you got that

Comment: sure! I will provide an answer (soon)

Comment: Good thing you included the word "either". Otherwise the grasshopper could do any distance with two jumps... 

Comment: @DrXorile you mean without it grasshopper can exploit 2D? But it's already specified that the grasshopper sits on a number line, which is 1D.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Throwing this here before actually checking anything, but

- any number that has 3 (or fewer) ones in its binary representation is trivially reached by jumping forward for each 1-bit.
- any number that has only 1 zero in its binary representation is easily reachable: jump to the nearest 2^n-1 (all ones) above the target with 2 hops, then flip that single bit to zero by jumping backwards.

so let's try the smallest one that doesn't fall to these:

> 39 (binary 100111)

Oops, has a lot of ones at the end, so we can do 32 + 8 - 1

Has to be

> **43** (binary 101011) then.

---

**EDIT: Proof of correctness**

We've already shown above that by construction, all smaller numbers can be reached by 3 jumps or fewer; the only thing left is to show that this number cannot. Let's do that recursively.

> - To get to 43 with the minimal number of hops, we'll need to do either **64-21** or **32+11**.
>
>  So we need to show that neither 21 nor 11 can be reached in 2 hops.
>
>  - - To get to 21 w/ min. hops, we'll need to do either **32-11** or **16+5**
>  - - To get to 11 (similarly), we'll need to do either **16-5** or **8+3**

And that's enough, because none of 11, 5 and 3 are powers of two, and as such, cannot be reached with a single hop.

Comment: very nice and intuitive solution

Comment: nice additional proof.

Answer (score 15):

A general answer for $h$ hops:

> The smallest number requiring $h$ hops to reach is $\frac{2*4^{h-1}+1}{3} = 1,3,11,43,171,683,2731,10923,\dots$, which is [A007583 in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007583).

> If a number $N$ takes $h$ hops to reach from 0, it also takes $h$ hops to return to 0 from. Each hop in the return trip for $N$ will either add or subtract 1 from $N$'s least significant 1, because any smaller hop will simply have to be cancelled later, and any larger hops can be considered after this hop is taken.
>  It turns out that there's a simple process for determining which direction to go: If the least significant 1 is next to another 1, add to it. Otherwise, subtract from it.
>  Why does this work? If you subtract when you would add, then either your next hop is still an add (you wasted a hop), or it is now a subtract (you spent two hops clearing a run of two that would have taken either one or two hops normally). Likewise, if you add when you should subtract, then either your next hop is still a subtract (you wasted a hop), or it is an add on three or more numbers (nothing gained or lost), or it is an add on two numbers (you'll have to add when you should be subtracting - run this test again).

What does this mean?

> Since each application of the above rule removes at least one 1, a number taking $h$ hops contains at least $h$ 1's.
>  Since the only hops that can remove multiple 1's are adds performed on runs of three or more 1's, every such run can be trimmed down to two to produce a smaller number with exactly $h$ 1's.
>  In such a number, sequences of $a$ adds followed by a subtract (an add cannot be the last hop) in the optimal path correspond to digit blocks of the form $0(01)^a1$. Since the block corresponding to $a+1$ can be obtained from the block for $a$ by replacing its final 1 with 011, and every minimal number with $h$ hops will consists purely of blocks spanning $2h$ digits, the smallest such number will consist of a single block that is as long as possible, whose binary digits look like $(10)^{h-2}11$, and this binary expansion can be shown to match the formula shown above.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful observations for the general case.

Comment: I prefer the following explanation to "why does it work": When we add 1 to rightmost 1, we flipped all 1s that are together and put 1 in the space of first 0. If we now subtract that generated 1, we did 2 operations to erase this group of 1s and leave the number the same. This means that with 2+ ones we lose nothing over subtracting. So, we should add, in case that generated 1 does not need to be subtracted and can be also added to. Meanwhile, if there is a single one, adding 1 cannot help over subtracting but can hurt, so we subtract.

Answer (score 8):

My solution is:

> $43 = 32 + 8 + 2 + 1$.

Firstly, note that the grasshopper's optimal strategy for any number between $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$ is to jump either $2^n$ or $2^{n+1}$ depending on which power of $2$ the number is closest to. This reduces the number to a number under $2^n$, taking one step.

Secondly, note that the grasshopper can reach all numbers under $8$ in at most $2$ steps. Therefore, generalizing this, it can reach all numbers under $16$ in at most $3$ steps. However, if we do direct enumeration, we can note that only numbers $11 = 8 + 2 + 1$ and $13 = 8 + 4 + 1$ take $3$ steps to reach.

We can then note that numbers from $16$ to $32$ still take only $3$ steps to reach. The only possible way for a number from $16$ to $32$ to take $4$ steps to reach is if some path that leads to it uses the sequences $8+2+1$ or $8+4+1$. However, if we add these to $16$, we find out that the numbers resulted are actually closer to $32$ than to $16$, meaning the grasshopper can easily find a shortest path.

Finally, the shortest path by the grasshopper to reach all numbers between $32$ and $48$ is moving $32$ steps, first, getting a number under $16$. Therefore, we can use our solution for the $16$-problem over again.  By our solution then, we have that all numbers between $32$ and $42 = 32+10$ take 3 steps to reach (all numbers from 1 to 10 take 2 steps to reach). But, we can verify $43 = 32 + 8 + 2 + 1$ takes 4 steps because it reduces to $13$ which takes $3$ steps and there are no shorter paths because reducing to $13$ is the optimal move.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar approach to Bass, but slightly different. It yielded the same result anyway.

The answer:

> 43

Approach:

> Consider the binary representation of the number, starting from the higher digits. For the prefix to be `10`, we need exactly one hop, because each (positive) hop corresponds to a digit in the binary number.

> For a prefix of `1...10` we need 2 hops. the first will create the number `10...00`, the second will be a backwards jump to create `1...10` (it can also be that the number ends with the sequence of `1`s).

> Then how do we continue? There are two options: if the previous step left us with a bunch of `0...0`, we can repeat it. Otherwise it left us with `1...1`, in which case we will do the exact same thing, but in reverse: We can either create a prefix `01` with one step or `0..01` with two.

Solution:

> So we'll have to split the answer to cases. If the number starts with `10` (1 hop), it can continue to `1010` (2 hops) and then `101011` or `10101010` to create two hops. The best would be `101011` (43).

> It could also continue to `1011..` (3 hops) and then `101101` (45).

> If the number starts with `11..` (2 hops) it can continue as `1101..` (3 hops) and then `110101` (53) or `1101110` (110).

> The lowest one being 43.